# htaccess Deny All for certain files and allow by IP for the rest

Tags: .htaccess

I've recently upgraded a web app and I want to combine the new and old htaccess into one file. Here is my new htaccess:

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

And my old htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 12.34.567.89
Allow from 12.34.567.88
```

My end goal is that No One can access the *.inc but only the approved IPs can access the rest of the folder.
Can I just concatenate these two rules in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 12.34.567.89
Allow from 12.34.567.88

<Files ~ "\.inc$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```